# I want to disable Zoom In and Out feature of web browser control in wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

```
 private void webBrowserDescription_LoadCompleted_1(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
 {
     this.webBrowserDescription.InvokeScript("eval", new[] { "document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild('<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width,user-scalable=no \">')"});
 }
```

But got An unknown error has occurred. `Error: 80020101`.

How can I resolve this to disable `Zoom in - Zoom Out` feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got Solution by chainging my way,here i used navigateToString instead of InvokeScript method:

```
BrowserControl.LoadCompleted += Browser_LoadCompleted;
private void Browser_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
  string myhtml = BrowserControl.SaveToString();
  string mataTag = "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=320,user-scalable=yes\" />";
  myhtml = html.Insert(html.IndexOf("<head>", 0) + 6, mataTag);
  BrowserControl.NavigateToString(html);
  BrowserControl.LoadCompleted -=  Browser_LoadCompleted;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no" />
```

Comment: Could you add some additional information, along with your answer?

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg,`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,  minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />`, you can go to [this](http://3g.cn) in your phone. and then open it by IE explore in the computer to view the source code, wish this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to use a meta tag in the page header?  I don't know if wp8 recognizes those or not.  e.g.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, 
maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, 
target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```